# Is there anyway to tell if a RSA public key pair is correct?

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I got a quiz question asking which of the following pair(n,e) is a correct RSA public key?

1. n = 437 and e = 7
2. n = 437 and e = 11

Hint 437 = 19*23

Is there anyway to tell is a RSA public key correct? Or I've must missed some important content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

The **2nd** one is incorrect. Because `gcd(e, lambda(n))` must be 1, but it is not in 2nd case.

**Long answer:**

Go through [RSA key generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)):

`n=437 and 437=19*23`, so p, q are 19, 23.

`lambda(437)=(p-1)*(q-1)=18*22`

Now we need to select `e` in a way `1<e<lambda(n)` **and** `gcd(e, lambda(n))=1` meaning `e` and `lambda(n)` are coprime.

But in 2nd case, `gcd(11, lambda(437))=11`, so they are not coprime and we cannot use `e=11`.